# Export Access Query to Excel - Check boxes show True/False

Tags: ms-access, ms-office, excel-2013

I'm testing exporting some of my MS Access queries to excel. My check boxes are showing true or false instead of yes or no. Any way to keep it as Yes/No?  At this time I'm not using any coding to do it, just the export button. The pivot tables and charts will be updated with new data from the queries as new customer information is entered over time. Any ideas of how to do this are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In query designer select the field with Yes/No data type and then in properties select `Yes/No` for `Format` property on General tab and `Text Box` for `Display Control` property on Lookup tab

**Update**

If used DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet for export to XLS, query field format doesn't matter, transfer procedure takes default format of Yes/No fields and converts into text like "True/False" (depends on language of Office user interface). In order to override default format, conversion from Yes/No to text should be done in query. If you cannot edit existing query, create new one with formulas in Yes/No fields like this:

```
MyYesNoField: IIf([MyTableOrQuery].[MyYesNoField],"Yes","No")
```

Comment: Forms use their own controls for data representation, query gives only 0 or -1 to them as data source, so changing this propery should not affect forms data presentation/